# Octave: move contour line in 3d?

Tags: plot, octave, matlab-figure

in Octave I want to create a contour line of a function in 3D and
then move it in the space:

```
x1=-4:0.1:4;

[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,x1);

Z= X.^2+2*Y.^2;

hx=contour(X,Y,Z,[4 4]);
```

So I get the contour.
How to move it?

I would like to translate it by adding a vector [a,b,c].

**EDIT:**

See here for example. Move the blue ellipse to the position of the yellow one.

[image: an ellipse moved]

Thanks

Karl

Comment: just add them to X,Y,Z

Comment: @ Andy did you try out your own proposal? If I add +4 to ze Z-values, the contour does not move :-)).

Comment: A contour is a 2D image, what kind of "move" rather than a color shift do you expect when incrementing Z?

Comment: @ Andy, did you try your own advice? Please do it. Now you come with something total different. If I run the code above, I get a curve in 3D. I want to move this curve to another position in the space, for example four units upwards. Therefore I ask, how to do it.

Comment: Your above code doesn't "get you a curve in 3D". contour3 would do but you cleary use `contour`

Comment: @ Andy, if I run the code, I get a curve in a 3D space. Did you run the code yourself?

Comment: of course I did

Comment: As it seems none understand what you want to do, it will better to add a sketch of the expected result.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Andy the contour is a 2D image as it is the projection of the intersection of a 3D curve with given planes parallel to the XY plane.
As example, the altitude curves on a geograhpical maps are contours, and the map is 2D.

To explain the difference between 3D and 2D contour, I plotted the 3D surface of your data and 3 multiple countours.
Instead of your height value of 4 I am using the 0,5,10..50 to have multiples contours for different values of Z

```
x1=-4:0.1:4; 
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,x1);
Z= X.^2+2*Y.^2;
subplot(2,2,1)
surf(X,Y,Z);
subplot(2,2,2)
contour(X,Y,Z,0:5:50);
subplot(2,2,3)
contour(X+2,Y+2,Z,0:5:50);
subplot(2,2,4)
contour(X,Y,Z+4,0:5:50);
print -djpg figure2.jpg
```

[image: Octave multiplot]

As you can see the subplot 1 (upper,left) is the 3D surface and the subplot 2 (upper,right) is a 2D image reporting all the projections for Z from 5 to 50 step 5.
The contour for Z=0 is just a point and not plotted.

On subplot 3 (bottom,left) we move the figure in the XY direction for X,Y = 2,2 .The countour shapes are not changed; the X,Y ranges instead of -4:4 are now -2:6.

On subplot 4 (bottom,right) we move the figure in the Z direction for a value 4.The contour shapes are different as the intersection with the planes parallel to XY plane 
are different.

Comment: @ matzeri, I fear we misunderstand each other. If I create a contour (appears for me in a 3D coordinate system)  or contour3 object, here it is an ellipse, I want to move this **graphical object** in 3D. Is there any way to use the handle _hx_ to shift it somehow?

Comment: Any image is plotted in a figure. You can manipulate the object or the figure: https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Manipulation-of-Plot-Objects.html#Manipulation-of-Plot-Objects https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Manipulation-of-Plot-Windows.html#Manipulation-of-Plot-Windows  You can move an image changing the paperposition https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Figure-Properties.html#Figure-Properties

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have clarified what you need we can propose a solution.
First we need to recover the coordinates of a chosen countour (Z=4) with `countourc`

```
x1=-4:0.1:4; 
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,x1);
Z= X.^2+2*Y.^2;
C=contourc(X,Y,Z,[4 4]);
```

There are 137 (x,y) points in the contour

```
size (C)
ans =

     2   138

C(:,1:4)
ans =

     4.000000    -0.280000    -0.200000    -0.100000
   137.000000    -1.400000    -1.406897    -1.412069
```

C(1,1) is the Z heigth and C(2,1) is the number of couples, so we can extract the original position of the countour with;

```
CX=C(1,2:end);
CY=C(2,2:end);
CZ=repmat([4],1,C(2,1));
```

and than plot in the original space position and with Z=0, that is the projection on the XY plane

```
plot3(CX,CY,CZ,"color","yellow");
hold on;
plot3(CX,CY,CZ-4,"color","blue");
print -djpg figure3.jpg
```

[image: 3D contour and projection]

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the confusion with contour and contour3. Now I have found a solution using contour3 as @andy proposed:

```
x1=-4:0.1:4;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x1,x1);
Z= X.^2+2*Y.^2;
contour3(X,Y,Z,[2 2]);
hold on
[hx,c]=contour3(X+1,Y+2,Z,[2 2]);
set(c,"zlevelmode","manual","zlevel",3)
```

This gives then:
[image]